# Multiple Google Admob account in app-ads.txt

Tags: admob

So we use 1 Admob account for our Android version apps, and 1 another Admob account for iOS version apps. The question is can we add our both Admob account to this app-ads.txt? Answers with reference links to Google docs is highly appreciated.

PS: In previously asked questions people aske they put 2 different Admob in one app so if they can add in this way, but my question is a little bit different, we use different Admobs for different platform Google-Apple, with same domain.

Comment: How did you end up doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Put them on multiple lines. Example:

```
google.com, pub-4548791236487963, DIRECT, f54c32dfa9876eb0
google.com, pub-7895412345798765, DIRECT, f54c32dfa9876eb0
```

Comment: is this tested before?

Comment: Yes, I did it in my apps and it worked like a charm.